# Question with that-clause, meaning

Tags: questions

I came across a question called "*question about that-clause*" (M. Swan- Practical English Usage). What I wish to understand is what kind of meaning these questions express. For instance, what are the differences between

> What did you say you wanted for Christmas.

and

> What did you want for Christmas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What did you **say** you wanted for Christmas?

The primary focus here is on what you said. What you said may or may not be what you really meant.

However,

> What did you **want** for Christmas?

is asking what you really wanted for Christmas.

Comment: Hm... ok, Thank you. But in general when we may use that kind of questions? For instance, when we're asking about what we don't really concern, are we?